# Making a Kubernetes Pod Publicly Accessible (Terraform)

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, splunk

I have an AWS EKS cluster that has a Helm Chart deployment for an application (Splunk) and it does spin up as Kubernetes pods that I can see.

I'm relatively new to EKS/Kubernetes and I'm not quite sure how to make the pods (in my case specifically for the Splunk Web access) available to be hit externally. e.g. I can port forward the Kubernetes pod for Splunk and hit at `localhost:<port>`, but I'm trying to find the proper way to hit at some kind of `<publicly available ip/address>` instead.

My first thought was to create some kind of load balancer for the cluster, but I don't know how I would hit the specific pod for Splunk and make that accessible at the address. I would think that putting the cluster on a load balancer would affect all of the pods in the cluster, but I don't know if that's true with my limited EKS/Kubernetes knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

you can expose your deployment by multiple ways, I'll mention some:

#### 1- by creating service with type loadbalancer

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myapp
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: myapp
  ports:
  - port: <Port>
    targetPort: <Target Port>
```

but note that this will create a load-balancer with every service you create, this is not efficient as well as it's more expensive. this can be useful in case you want to test something very fast then change type of service later. just make sure to update the security group of eks to allow access to your IP after the change, but yet i don't recommend that So, let's go to the second option.

#### 2- expose your service via ingress

create clusterIP service then expose it using ingress resource

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: <name>
  annotations:
    <some annotations>
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: <host.com>
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: <the-name-of-service-you-created>
            port:
              number: <your-port>
  tls:
  - hosts:
    -  <host.com>
    secretName: <secretname of certificate>
```

#### 3- you can use other service types:

NodePort - Exposes the Service on each Node's IP at a static port (the NodePort). To make the node port available, Kubernetes sets up a cluster IP address, the same as if you had requested a Service of type: ClusterIP.

ExternalName - Maps the Service to the contents of the externalName field (e.g. foo.bar.example.com), by returning a CNAME record with its value. No proxying of any kind is set up. This type requires v1.7 or higher of kube-dns, or CoreDNS version 0.0.8 or higher.

you can check the [documentation of k8s service resource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) for more details to decide which one suits you more.